# Error in parsing an input string to int value in c#

Tags: c#

First `if` works great

Second `if` throws an exception

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number and click enter, continue doing this process ");
        Console.WriteLine("When you finish, just click enter without giving any input");
        int i = 0;
        int[] numbersArray;
        List<int> numbersList = new List<int>();

        while (true)
        {
            String numInput = Console.ReadLine();
            numbersList.Add(Int32.Parse(numInput));
            numbersArray = numbersList.ToArray();
            if (i >= 1)
            {
                if (numbersArray[i] < numbersArray[i - 1])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your series is not going up!");
                    break;
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }

                if (numbersArray[i] > numbersArray[i - 1])
                {
                    if (numInput == "") { 
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
            Console.WriteLine("You entered this series: ");
            for (int j = 0; j < numbersArray.Length; j++)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(" " + numbersArray[j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The length of the series youve entered is: " + numbersArray.Length);


    }
}
```

Comment: whats the error? Also you have tagged python and c.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java, Android, Python or C?

Comment: You cannot reach the second if because if you give an empty string to Int32.Parse it will crash. Use instead Int32.TryParse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't parse a string wihout digits like numInput = ""

EDIT: Try this code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number and click enter, continue doing this process ");
        Console.WriteLine("When you finish, just click enter without giving any input");
        int i = 0;
        int[] numbersArray = new []{1};
        List<int> numbersList = new List<int>();

        while (true)
        {

            String numInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (numInput == null || !numInput.All(char.IsDigit)) continue;

            if (numInput != "")
            {
                numbersList.Add(Int32.Parse(numInput));
                numbersArray = numbersList.ToArray();

                if (i >= 1)
                {
                    if (numbersArray[i] < numbersArray[i - 1])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your series is not going up!");
                        break;
                        Environment.Exit(0); // <-- Code is unreachable!
                    }
                }
            i++;
            }
            else if(i >= 1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("You entered this series: ");
        foreach (int t in numbersArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" " + t);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The length of the series youve entered is: " + numbersArray.Length);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: what is !numInput.All(char.IsDigit)

Comment: Sorry, I was away. The ! is a boolean inverter. numInput.All(char.IsDigit) checks whether the string numInput only has Digits. If thats the case the method return value is true. Can you please mark my post as answer!?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to look at a index not existing.

Not sure of your language but I guess numbersArray[0] is the first index and numbersArray[1] is the second. So when you input your first number then you try to look at numbersArray[1] which doesn't exist.

Comment: No, it has a check on the value of i being bigger than zero.